# Split routes into separate modules in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I'm working on an Angular 6 application. Currently I'm struggling with routing. I'm interested, whether mine structure, what I have imagined can work or not. So it looks like this:

App module - contains main routing with some parent route, where layout is defined. Like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
{
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
    // {
    //   path: 'brands',
    //   loadChildren: 'app/modules/brands/brands.module#BrandsModule',
    //   pathMatch: 'prefix'
    // }
    ]
}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), BrandsModule, ItemsModule],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [BosRouteLoader]
})
export class RoutingModule {}
```

One of mine feature module defines its own routing in a module like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'brands',
    children: [
    { path: '', component: BrandListComponent },
    { path: ':id', component: BrandDetailComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ]
}];


@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class BrandsRoutingModule {}
```

I would like to achieve that every feature module will define its own routing and  those routes are registered as a child routes of the App module.

With lazy loading I can manage it but then I have to define one more route always in mine App module, however I just want to define it in feature module.

If I do it without lazy loading, then mine parent route in App component is never hit. So if I go to **http://localhost/brands** it will load the appropriate BrandLisComponent but without LayoutComponent.

Is ther a way to define routes in feature module and register them as a child of main main routing module?

Comment: If you're using child-routing for `BrandRountingModule`, you need to give it a `component` property, not only `children`! and then use `<router-outlet>` tag to address those children. But generally I didn't get what you want to achieve. What is ItemListComponent and localhost/items ?!

Comment: @imans77 I want to achieve that if I go to /brands route then LayoutComponent and BrandListComponent will be active. Right now only brandComponent is active without layout...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept is that you define a module routing in your higher-level module and then define its children in your desired module.

So in your case, you need to tell the angular that, hey when someone goes to `brands` route, use `BrandsRoutingModule` routings.

So in your app module, you're going to have:

```
{
    path: 'brands',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/brands/brands.module#BrandsModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
}
```

This tells that you need to load the routing of that module if the user goes to `/brand`.

Then in your `BrandsRoutingModule`, you need to define routes to be:

```
{
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: BrandListComponent },
        { path: ':id', component: BrandDetailComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ]
}
```

So whenever we route to `/brands`, we shall see the `LayoutComponent` as a main route relative to that and then the `BrandListComponent` and others will come as his children. But to show his children, you also need to put this line of code in your `layout.component.html`:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

this tells angular that, hey if he's going to for example `/brands/2`, you need to load the `BrandDetailComponent` **inside** the `LayoutComponent`, literally as his child.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @thadam If your problem is solved then mark this the correct answer, and if it's not, tell me where I went wrong :)

Answer (score 2):

Imans77's answer works for lazy loaded modules (although the string from of LoadChildren [is now deprecated](https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildren)). However, with eager loaded modules, if you want to tidy up the main routes module and split the file accross different modules, you could try the following approach:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const MODULE_ROUTES = [...module1Routes, module2Routes];

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'path1', component: Path1Component },
  { path: 'path2', component: Path2Component },
  ...MODULE_ROUTES,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Instead of declaring all children of every component/module in the main routing file, you could create a *.route.ts file for each feature module, in which you could just declare and export routes in a normal way. For example:

```
export const module1Routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'brands',
    children: [
        { path: '', component: BrandListComponent },
        { path: ':id', component: BrandDetailComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
    ]
}];
```

By importing it in the main routing file, they would immediately be available for Angular.